# Ogre3D 204 errors on setup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ogre3d

I have tried to setup Ogre3D in Visual Studio 2012 Express.
I have followed every step in http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Visual+Studio

but when I compile it, says 204 errors in the Ogre code. I seriously doubt that is true since I can't find any others with the same problem.

These two lines in yvals.h have 4 errors

```
public:
__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Lockit(const _Lockit&) = delete;
_Lockit& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator=(const _Lockit&) = delete;
```

Error C2059: syntax error: ';'
Error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
Error C2059: syntax error: ';'
Error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Again I doubt that these errors are because of Ogre, but more likely something I have done. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Ogre SDK, it comes with binaries and everything to get started. The error might seem to be a problem with definitions but I need more information about it.